# How to paint components in layers in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I have big problem with coding graphic part of my app, where I need to have components one on top of each other:

1. First I have `JFrame` (with fixed size)
2. In it I have two `JPanel` components. I want them to have colour background.
   That's the easy part.
3. On one of the `JPanel` components I want to draw fixed shapres - rectangles, lanes, etc. Here I have problem, that I have two classes: one extends `JPanel` and is background for this part and second extends `JComponent` and represents element I draw (there is several elements). I don't know how to draw the elements in the `JPanel` - I tried several methods and nothing showed up. It's important to me that the JComponents should be drawn and conected only with this `JPanel`, not with whole frame.
4. On top of that I want to have moving shapes. It's easy when I have only frame and let's say rectangle, because I only change position and call `repaint()` method, but how to do this to make the moving shapes be connected to and be inside `JPanel` and to left previous layers in their place?

For my tries I created few classes with rectangles:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    public Main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1200, 900);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel background = new JPanel();
        background.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        GreenRect gr = new GreenRect();
        gr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,800));
        background.add(gr, BorderLayout.WEST);


        RedRect rr = new RedRect();
        rr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,800));
        background.add(rr, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.add(background);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}

class GreenRect extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<BlackRect> r = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<MovingRec> m = new ArrayList<>();

   public GreenRect() {
       setBackground(Color.green);
       addRec(10,10);
       addRec(50,50);
       addRec(100,100);
       addRec(1000,1000);
   }

   public void addRec(int x, int y) {
       r.add(new BlackRect(x,y));
   }
}


class RedRect extends JPanel {
    public RedRect() {
        setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}

class BlackRect extends JComponent {
    int x, y;
    int w = 100, h = 100;

    public BlackRect (int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}

class MovingRec  extends JComponent {
    int x, y;
    int w = 20, h = 20;

    public MovingRec (int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }

    public void update() {
        x += 5;
        y += 5;
    }
}
```

and now I have problems with points 3 and 4, because I can't place black rectangles on background and moving rectangles on the top.

I will be grateful for all help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to (and shouldn’t) extend `BlackRect` and `MovingRect` from `JComponent`.

For example, `BlackRect` could be a simple object, like:

```
class BlackRect {
    int x, y;
    int w = 100, h = 100;

    public BlackRect(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
}
```

You should override `GreenRect`’s paint method, to paint rectangles on that panel:

```
public GreenRect extends JPanel {
    // Existing members 

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (BlackRect black_rect : r) {
            black_rect.paint(g2d);
        }

        // Also paint list of moving rectangles here
    }
}
```

When `GreenRect.repaint()` is called, it will paint its background, and all rectangles from the `r` (and `m` list when you add that code).  If the `m` rectangles have had their positions updated, they will be drawn at their new positions, so they will appear to be moving.  Since moving rectangles are drawn last, they would appear “on top”.

Use a Swing [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to drive the animation.   When the timer expires, it should move all of the moving rectangles slightly (ie, call `MovingRec.update()`), and call `repaint()` on `GreenRect`.